# not able to test asp.net web service from remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, remote-access

we have built a asp.net web service application that we test on the local machine.

We have deployed it on the client's server and tested it there as well.

The web service returns JSON data, not xml.

But when the we try to access that URL from a remote machine, we cannot see the input fields for taking the parameters. it shows the list of the methods in the web service but when we click on them there's no text fields for input.

We'd like to access the web services remotely and test them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused when you say, 'input fields'. What exactly are you referring to? Web services in general only exposes methods that you can call.

Comment: if i understood correctly you are able see all the methods,but when you click on that method the input fields are not showing to enter right?lets say `Add(int a ,int b)` but when you open this webmethod,you are not seeing textboxes to enter these A and B values Right?

Comment: Is this a WCF service, or a legacy ASMX service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you have the following in your config file.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

Really though you should probably be using something like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) for testing services as the tests are re-runnable ect.